# CSS :active and iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a div, with id="menu_item" in HTML which has two css styles: one default and a different style when div is "active" from a mouse event.

CSS:

```
div.menu_item

{

    background-image    : url(../images/button_unselected.svg);

    background-repeat   : no-repeat;

    background-position : center;      

}



div.menu_item:active

{

    background-image    : url(../images/button_selected.svg);

    background-repeat   : no-repeat;

    background-position : center; 

}
```

When I click on this item, the iframe (iframe 1) which contains this item becomes invisible (visibility = none) and a new iframe (iframe 2) appears (visibility = inline). This new iframe is similar to the first, and has the same menu buttons.

Now, when I return to iframe 1 by navigating the iframe 2's menu, the div that enabled me to leave iframe 1 in the first place is still considered "active" until any mouse event is detected (movement, button press etc).

Is there any way to "kill" this css active tag so that the non-active version is displayed when navigating to the page? I want the default non-active versions of each div to be shown when first navigating to the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ":active" pseudoclass only applies while you're holding the mouse button down on an element.

Comment: When navigate to the new iframe via Javascript, the mouse button is still down, so when I return to the original iframe, no other mouse event has been detected. I think this is what is causing the issue. When I navigate to new iframe, any mouse events are applied to that iframe. I would think that when you navigate to the original iframe where you pressed the button, all css active "states" would be reset, but this is not the case.

Comment: hmm well that could be. I don't know of any way in JavaScript to affect pseudoclasses. However, you could always add a class to the element that has a CSS rule *after* the `:active` rule to un-do it.

Comment: ^This would work a treat

Comment: I was trying to avoid changing the class or background manually as there is more than one button. Thanks for the idea though.